# jQuery slideToggle and CSS border-radius property show unusually in IE10

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, internet-explorer-10, css

I am using MVC4 and in my page I took 4 div and all div. I have JSFiddle URL to check my exactly problem.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaur1982/9FmdP/)

Please run this in only in IE10, because in below IE10 or any other browser it working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".HomeContent").hide();
        jQuery(".HomeDivHeading").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".HomeContent").slideToggle(250);
        });
    });
```

In IE10 when I slide down any din it shows like this
[image]

I want to resolve this problem when I slide down div it look like wired and after some time it shows automatically corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a strange browser behavior. I've found out the solution as given belove;

```
.HomeDivHeading {
    background-color: #BBC0C4;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    display: inline-block; /* changed from block to inline-block*/
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```