# Bug in IE11 slideDown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with IE11 and jQuery's function .slideDown()

When I press a button to call the function .slideDown() it looks like the image below.

[image]

If I move the mouse the indentation (or what it could be called) disapperas, but if I collapse and expand there it is again.

Does anyone know if this is a known error, or have any suggestion on how I can solve this?

EDIT: Updated with some code.

html

```
<div class="small-info">
    <div class="expande">
        <span id="show-more">read more</span><span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="extended-info" hidden>
....
</div
```

js

```
$('#show-more').on('click', function() {
    $('.small-info').slideUp();
    $('.extended-info').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's common error, maybe some HTML structure or JS/CSS is messing it. `how I can solve this` - no code = no help. Voting to close question

Comment: @Justinas You are right, but since she is updated the question, please remove the close vote.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I added some code. But I dont know if it will do any difference, because it is very basic..  Atleast I have heard from one person that it isn't a common error, thats something.

Comment: @SannaWidell This is how stackoverflow works. We need code, to examine the problem, a lot of time it is just a typo, or user error, not browser specific.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as in this question, [jQuery slideToggle and CSS border-radius propery show wired in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430675/jquery-slidetoggle-and-css-border-radius-propery-show-wired-in-ie10)

And it was fixed by adding following to extended-info & small-info:

```
display:inline-block;
```

instead of just display:block;